# Best way to create a new columns of numerics based on different string values in different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 5 different possible string values in 3 columns that I want to be converted to numeric values in 3 new columns.

```
Columns:
1_month, 6_month, 12_month

Possible Values:
High
Above Average
Average
Below Average
Low

I'd like to create 3 new columns:
1_month_int, 6_month_int, 12_month_int

Then map the numerics from the string values as:
High = 5
Above Average = 4
Average = 3
Below Average = 2
Low = 1
```

I have tried copying the column then finding and replacing values for a single column, then changing the column type to numeric when done.  It works, but only works for 1 column:

```
df['1_month_int'] = df['1_month']
df['1_month_int'].replace("High",5, inplace=True)
df['1_month_int'].replace("Above Average",4, inplace=True)
df['1_month_int'].replace("Average",3, inplace=True)
df['1_month_int'].replace("Below Average",2, inplace=True)
df['1_month_int'].replace("Low",1, inplace=True)
df['1_month_int'] = pandas.to_numeric(df['1_month_int'])
```

I can't get it work for multiple columns at once:

```
df['1_month_int'] = df['1_month']
df['6_month_int'] = df['6_month']
df['12_month_int'] = df['12_month']
df[['3_month_int', '6_month_int', '12_month_int']/
      .replace("High",5, inplace=True)
etc..
```

I am sure there's a better way.

I am very new to Pandas and am struggling through the learning curve of how to think about and solve problems like this.

I would greatly appreciate any help being pointed in the right direction on the best practices to handle data manipulation like this in Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use `Series.map`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1_month':['High', 'Above Average'], '6_month':['Average','Below Average'], '12_month':['Low','Low']
})
map_ = {'High' : 5,'Above Average' : 4,'Average' : 3,'Below Average' : 2,'Low' : 1}
for c in df.columns:
    df[c+'_int'] = df[c].map(lambda x: map_[x])
df
```

- output

```
    1_month         6_month     12_month    1_month_int     6_month_int     12_month_int
0   High            Average         Low         5                3             1
1   Above Average   Below Average   Low         4                2             1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is there some book, tutorial, etc. that you found very useful in learning pandas?

Comment: I dont know a good book for pandas. But you can learn good amount of pandas by doing yourself, reading documentation and most importantly read top stack overflow questions on pandas.

Answer (score 0):

you can use series's map function to map the value to given number like below

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

values = ["High", 
"Above Average", 
"Average", 
"Below Average", 
"Low", ]

mapper = {key: i+1 for i, key in enumerate(values[::-1])}

columns = "1_month,6_month,12_month".split(",")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(values,(10,3)), columns=columns)

for col in columns:
    df[f"{col}_int"] = df[col].map(mapper)

display(df)
```